# Convert an Array of 3 numbers to associated letters

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im learning JS and have set myself the challenge to re-create a football league table, from an array of match results.

Everything is going really well and I'm almost complete, but I can't filter my 'FORM GUIDE' array to their corresponding Letters.

I have the points scored over the last 5 games ONLY outputted as an array (below);

```
[3, 1, 3, 0, 3]
```

But I'd like to output this as 3 = W, 1 = D, 0 = L.

So...
W, D, W, L, W

Can someone please explain how I can do this?

Thank you

```
'use strict';

// Tottenham's Premier League scores & points 21-22 //
//--------------------------------------------------//

const scoresPoints = [
    [1, 0, 3], // Watford
    [1, 1, 1], // Southampton
    [3, 0, 3], // Crystal Palace
    [2, 2, 1], // Liverpool
    [3, 0, 3], // Norwich
    [2, 0, 3], // Brentford
    [2, 1, 3], // Leeds
    [0, 0, 1], // Everton
    [3, 2, 3], // Newcastle
    [0, 3, 0], // Man U
    [0, 1, 0], // West Ham
    [2, 1, 3], // Villa
    [1, 3, 0], // Arsenal
    [0, 3, 0], // Chelsea
    [0, 3, 0], // Crystal Palace
    [1, 0, 3], // Watford
    [1, 0, 3], // Wolves
    [1, 0, 3], // Man City
];

// Define The functions & arrays--------------------//
//--------------------------------------------------//

let tottenhamScores;
let totalTottenhamGoals;
let totalTottenhamPoints;
let totalOpponentsGoals;
let tottenhamForm = [];
// The goals scored by Tottenham
const tottenhamGoals = [];
// The points scored by Tottenham
const tottenhamPoints = [];
// The goals scored by the opponents
const opponentsGoals = [];

// Filter the data from each array------------------//
//--------------------------------------------------//

for (let i = 0; i < scoresPoints.length; i++) {
    tottenhamScores = scoresPoints[i][0];
    // Just Tottenham's goals
    tottenhamGoals.push(tottenhamScores);
    // Just Tottenham's points
    const leaguePoints = scoresPoints[i][2];
    tottenhamPoints.push(leaguePoints);
    // Just the opponents goals
    const opponentsScores = scoresPoints[i][1];
    opponentsGoals.push(opponentsScores);
    // Just Tottenham's Form
    const leagueForm = scoresPoints[i][2];
    tottenhamForm.push(leagueForm);
}

// Adding up the arrays-----------------------------//
//--------------------------------------------------//

// Adding up Tottenham's goals
for (let i = 0; i < tottenhamGoals.length; i++) {
    totalTottenhamGoals = tottenhamGoals.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
}
// Adding up Tottenham's points
for (let i = 0; i < tottenhamPoints.length; i++) {
    totalTottenhamPoints = tottenhamPoints.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
}
// Adding up the opponents goals
for (let i = 0; i < opponentsGoals.length; i++) {
    totalOpponentsGoals = opponentsGoals.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }, 0);
}

// Last 5 games-------------------------------------//
//--------------------------------------------------//

// Find the individual values
function occurrence(pointValues, value) {
    return pointValues.filter(v => v === value).length;
}
const win = occurrence(tottenhamPoints, 3);
const draw = occurrence(tottenhamPoints, 1);
const loss = occurrence(tottenhamPoints, 0);

// Filter to last five games
function lastFiveGames(form, five) {
    form = tottenhamForm.slice(0, five);
    return form;
}
const latestForm = lastFiveGames(tottenhamForm, 5);

// Convert points to represented letters
const letteredResult = latestForm.map(result => {
    switch (result) {
        case 0:
            return 'L';
        case 1:
            return 'D';
        case 3:
            return 'W';
        default:
            return 'No Form To Display';
    }
});

// Print the statement & table----------------------//
//--------------------------------------------------//

console.log(
    `SUMMARY
-------- 
-------- 
Throughout the 2021-22 Premier League season, Tottenham Hotspur have scorred ${totalTottenhamGoals} goals and conceeded ${totalOpponentsGoals}.
    
This has gained Tottenham Hotspur ${totalTottenhamPoints} points to date.

(Dropping ${
        scoresPoints.length * 3 - totalTottenhamPoints
    } points throughout the season from the maximum of ${
        scoresPoints.length * 3
    } available).
   
    TABLE & FORM GUIDE ---
    ----------------------
    ${scoresPoints.length} Played
    ${win} Wins
    ${draw} Draws
    ${loss} Losses
    ${totalTottenhamGoals} For
    ${totalOpponentsGoals} Against
    ${totalTottenhamGoals - totalOpponentsGoals} Goal Difference
    ${totalTottenhamPoints} POINTS IN TOTAL
    
    FORM (Last 5 Games) ${letteredResult}
    ----------------------
    ----------------------`
);
```

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: can you please elaborate on the logic here? What if the point is 4?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: 4 can never occur as the only points that are available are 3,1,0. I tried lots of solutions with my limited knowledge without luck, but the last answer using map has worked a treat. I will study both solutions and work out how they are working. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I've added all the code that i've written - to the initial question and I used the simple switch statement from ABDULLOKH to solve this question. I seem to be getting accused of not putting my own effort in, (when I really am) @Shubaker. Sorry, I should have posted the code that i'd tried writing in the initial question, sorry if I offended you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with `Array.map` and a nice `switch` statement. Try this way:

```js
const arr = [3, 1, 3, 0, 3]

const matched = arr.map(result => {
  switch(result){
    case 0:
      return 'L'
    case 1:
      return 'D'
    case 3:
      return 'W'
    default:
      return 'X'
  }
})

console.log(matched)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let arr = [3, 1, 3, 0, 3];

let arrMap = arr.map((i) => {
  if (i == 3) return "W";
  if (i == 0) return "L";
  return "D"
})


console.log(arrMap)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map:

```
[3, 1, 3, 0, 3].map(e => { if (e == 3) return "W";  if (e == 1) return "D"; if (e == 0) return "L"; throw `Unexpected value: ${e}`; })
```

Comment: Like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70556053/402037). And why does this no-effort question deserve an answer in the first place?

Comment: @Andreas That other answer is oversimplified.

Comment: The other answer does the exact same as yours - minus the unnecessary `throw`: _"4 can never occur as the only points that are available are 3,1,0"_

Comment: @Andreas That's your coding opinion. Variable input should always be handled with consistency regardless of the unlikeliness.

Comment: Thank you. This has worked a treat, I'll pick it apart to better understand the arrow function, but thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this clean and simple using `map` and an object acting as Enum where the key will represent the points and the value will represent the result char.

```js
const array = [3, 1, 3, 0, 3];
const cases = {0: 'L', 1: 'D', 3: 'W'};

const matches = array.map(e => cases[e]);

console.log(matches)
```

More about `map` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `map`, you could also use `forEach`. The main difference is that `map` will return a new array, whereas `forEach` doesn't return anything and can be used to change the original array. Here is how:

```js
const logic = {
  3: 'W',
  1: 'D',
  0: 'L'
}

const data = [3, 1, 3, 0, 3];

data.forEach((value, key) => data[key] = logic[value]);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [3, 1, 3, 0, 3, 2, 4];
const data = arr.map(v => ['L','D','_','W'][v] || '_');

console.log( data );
```